# chrome.input.ime - Switch between languages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ime

I am creating an application which supports multiple regional languages using "Google Input Tool" chrome extension.
can I switch between input languages on "onfocus()" event of an element?

I have searched on the net and come across "chrome.input.ime"
but don't know how to manage it with JavaScript

I found Extension ID "mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab"

and need something to do like
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ up: 1 });

Can anyone help?

~Manoj

Comment: I found Extension ID "mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab"

and need something to do like
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ up: 1 });

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.input.ime` allows you to implement a **new** input method on **Chrome OS only.** So it's not what you seek.

It does not seem like you can control the GIT extension from your code.

You suggest messaging the extension; however, it does *not* listen to any external messaging events - I have explicitly verified that. So it wouldn't work.